# Persistent network disconnection with Intel Wireless AC 9462 drivers

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers

My laptop (running Windows 10 Home edition, version 10.0.19044) has been continually disconnecting from the internet. Opening device manager shows that my network driver (Intel (R) Wireless-AC 9462) is not working, under its device status it shows

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.
```

I have **already tried** attempting the below in chronological order with no success, they all eventually lead to my network driver erroring out again:

- Checking to see if Airplane mode was enabled (it was not)
- Disabling and re-enabling the network driver
- Rebooting my laptop
- Attempting to update my drivers (letting windows search automatically, to which windows already determined I had the most up to date drivers) and also using external software to update them (Driver Booster 9 : https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php)
- Uninstalling my drivers and deleting the current driver software before reinstalling them from the intel website (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html)
- Attempting a hard reboot, whereby I power off the laptop (pressing and holding the power button), remove it from its power supply, and turning it back on
- Attempting a hard reboot along with a driver reinstall. **This actually worked and got the network driver working again. However, after about 10-15 minutes the network driver failed again with the same error**
- A complete factory reset of my laptop before updating the OS again to the latest update (cumulative 2022 June update : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-14-2022-kb5014699-os-builds-19042-1766-19043-1766-and-19044-1766-5c81d49d-0b6e-4808-9485-1f54e5d1bb15). **Again this also worked and got the network driver working again. However I faced the exact same issue, after about 10-15 minutes the network driver failed again with the same error**
- Installing OEM drivers

Answer (score 0):

> A complete factory reset of my laptop before updating the OS again to
> the latest update (cumulative 2022 June update

The wireless card appears to have a hardware error.

Perhaps you or a local shop could try re-seating the card to see if that provides a permanent repair.

You might see if the shop is able to replace the wireless card.

I suggest getting a USB Wireless card and trying that. Make sure drivers are available for your laptop.

Comment: I suspected so as well even though I was in denial after the factory reset